# LINQ multiple condition on "on" clause

Tags: linq

I have  a query which have multiple conditions on on clause

```
SELECT * 

 FROM   
       CATALOGITEM  with (nolock) INNER JOIN CATALOG with (nolock) ON
       CATALOGITEM.catalog_id = CATALOG.catalog_id and not(catalog.catalog_id = 21) AND NOT(catalog.catalog_id = 20)

       INNER JOIN PRODUCT with (nolock)  ON   
         CATALOGITEM.s_num = PRODUCT .s_num   
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_DETAIL with (nolock)  ON 
       PRODUCT_DETAIL.s_num = PRODUCT.s_num      
           WHERE
           (  
              CATALOGITEM.publish_code = 'upd' OR  
              CATALOG_ITEM.publish_code = 'ins' OR  
              PRODUCT.publish_code = 'upd' OR  
              PRODUCT.publish_code = 'ins'  
           )  

       and
       (CATALOG.unit_id = bu.unit_id)
```

How to write this in LINQ.

Please advice.

Comment: Move additional conditions to `where`.

Comment: btw, it's better to use SQL operator `IN`: `.. WHERE CATALOGITEM.publish_code IN ('upd, 'ins') OR PRODUCT.publish_code IN ('upd', 'ins')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you're missing a join to PRODUCT table?

Anyway, this should get you started.

```
var query = (from ci in db.catalogitem
         join c in db.catalog on ci.catalog_id equals c.catalog_id
         join p in db.products on ci.s_num equals p.s_num
         join pd in db.productdetail on p.s_num equals pd.s_num into tempprods
         from prods in tempprods.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where !(c.catalog_id.Contains(21, 20))
         && (ci.publish_code.Contains('upd','ins')) ||
            (p.publish_code.Contains('upd','ins'))
         select ci)
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually this is a small portion of query.the query consist of many left outer joins also.How to go abt that.
updated the original question.

Comment: Answer updated. For future, suggest you try doing it yourself. I gave you some guidance and answered original question, only way to learn is to take some examples and try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the (NOLOCK) hints, I have [blogged a handy solution](http://ryancoder.blogspot.com/2010/06/execute-linq-queries-without-locking.html) using extension methods in C#.  Note that this is the same as adding nolock hints to every table in the query.